# How do Thomists prove that: "Everything that exists must exist by something."?

Tags: aristotle, aquinas, principle-of-non-contradiction, principle-of-sufficient-reason

One variation of principle of sufficient reason that Thomists use is:

**Everything that exists must exist by something.**

How do they prove such a statement? In particular, why can not something just exist (*de facto*) and not by anything else?

**Edit.**

I meant to use variation of sufficent reason which says: **Whatever is, has that whereby it is**.

This was used by Jacques Maritain in his [Preface to Metaphyscis](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.207116/page/n108):

> We have thus brought out the notion of  sufficient reason. It is that
>   in virtue of which an  object is. We must, therefore, enunciate the
>   principle  of sufficient reason in one of the two following ways: 
>   Everything which is, to the extent to which it is, possesses  a
>   sufficient reason for its beings that is to say, is grounded  in
>   being, so that, to put it in another way, it is capable  of explaining
>   itself to the intellect, though not  necessarily to our intellect;
>   whatever is, is intelligibly  determined; whatever is, has that
>   whereby it is. Both these  formulas must be taken in the most general
>   sense.

Later he [tries](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.207116/page/n109) to reduce it to the principle of non-contradiction:

> At a later stage we can reduce, or rather logically  attach, the
>   principle of sufficient reason to the principle  of identity, by a
>   reductio ad absurdum. This is a reflex  operation which may, for
>   example, be described  compendiously as follows. The expression in
>   virtue of  whichy when we say that in virtue of which an object  is,
>   must have a meaning or be meaningless. If it  is meaningless
>   philosophy is futile, for philosophers  look for a sufficient ground
>   of things. If, on the other  hand, it has a meaning it is evident that
>   in virtue of  the principle of non-contradiction it is identical with 
>   the meaning of the phrase that without which an object  is not. If,
>   therefore, anything exists which has no  sufficient reason for its
>   existence, that is to say which  has neither in itself nor in
>   something else, that in  virtue of which it is, this object exists and
>   does not  exist at the same time. It does not exist because it  lacks
>   that without which it does not exist. This  reductio ad absurdum
>   proves that to deny the principle  of sufficient reason is to deny the
>   principle of identity.

To this I would respond that to deny of PSR is the same as to deny the PNC **or accept that philosophy is futile**, as Maritain says above.

Why (do Thomists) not accept that philosophy is futile (ie. accept that world at its core is not intelligible)? Why (do Thomists) accept that the world is intelligible rather than that it is not?

**Edit 2.**

As Mark Andrews noted in the comment Maritain quote needs to add italic to better understand his point. I have no time to do that so feel free to use the link on his book to read it with italics and all that.

As for the answer to my question, I think that Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P., answers my question in God: His Existence and His Nature vol. 1 (link to it is in Geremia answer, so I will accept his answer). Other answers also add some important points so I am thankful for those too.

Comment: They do not prove it, they postulate it. One can support it by empirical induction or by *a priori* arguments that identify explanations with causes, see [Leibniz's versions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sufficient-reason/#WhyDidLeibBeliPSR), for example.

Comment: @Conifold: that is incorrect. Not only do they not postulate it, they explicitly deny it. Your link to an explanation of Leibniz's PSR seems unobjectionable though.

Comment: @JaysonVirissimo If you are talking about existing by itself that is included in the shorthand motto.

Comment: @Conifold perhaps you are right, but given the final question asked by Thom, I think it more likely that they misunderstand the proposition, rather than are just using an abbreviated form of it.

Comment: @Thom. Could you give a thomist reference in which this principle is asserted? Is it a primary or a secondary source? A well known thomist principle is " everything that moves must be moved by something else".

Comment: @RayLittleRock Yes. Jacques Maritain in his Preface to Metaphysics says: **whatever is, has that whereby it is.** He even goes to reduce it to principle of non contradiction but I am not satisfied with his proof.

Comment: The Maritain quotes need a little work. Maritain’s use of italics adds a lot to understanding his point, but the quotes above do not include these.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thomists affirm theism, but God would be a counterexample to your proposition as stated: God is something "that exists" in Himself; He does not "exist by something [else]".

## Thomists' principle of sufficient reason (PSR)

A more accurate statement of Thomists' version of PSR is ([Philosophical Axiom](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/catholicteaching/philosophy/axiomata.htm) 7.1):

> Everything has sufficient reason of being either in itself or in another.
> <sub>Omne ens habet rationem sufficientem sui essendi in se aut in alio.</sub>

## PSR is indemonstrable.

PSR, like other metaphysical principles* such as [the principle of non-contradiction (PNC), is true but not directly demonstrable](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/46668/2014).

As Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P., explains in [*God: His Existence and His Nature* vol. 1](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3123), §24, pp. 181-191 (PDF pp. 98-103), PSR can be reduced to PNC indirectly, via a *reductio ad absurdum*.

Discussing PNC, St. Thomas writes ([*Summa Theologica* I-II q. 94 a. 2](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS094.html#FSQ94A2THEP1) co.): "on this principle all others are based" ("*super hoc principio omnia alia fundantur*").

---

*Réginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P., lists the following metaphysical first principles in his [*Reality: A Synthesis of Thomistic Thought*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3033) Chapter 56: Realism And First Principles:

> metaphysical principles: The principle of contradiction or identity,<sup>1380</sup> that of sufficient reason,<sup>1381</sup> that of efficient causality,<sup>1382</sup> and that of finality.<sup>1383</sup> These principles, we say, are true, because it is evident that they are primary laws, not only of our mind but of all reality. They are not merely existential judgments, but express objective and universal impossibilities. Never and nowhere can a thing simultaneously exist and not exist, can a thing be without its raison d’être, can a non-necessary thing exist without cause, can a thing act without any purpose. Metaphysical principles admit no exception.
>
> ---
>
> 1380. Being is being, non-being is non-being, or, being is not non-being.
> 1381. Everything that exists has its raison d’être, intrinsic or extrinsic.
> 1382. Every contingent being depends on an efficient cause.
> 1383. Every agent, including natural agents not endowed with cognition, acts for an end.

Comment: I meant to say: **whatever is, has that whereby it is**. If I accept the principle of non-contradiction, what would be wrong with saying: "whatever is, just de facto exists and that's all"? Where would in that case contradiction arise (if it would)?

Comment: @Thom "_whatever is, just de facto exists and that's all_" This statement seems to imply that everything is a self-subsisting being. That's different from the principle of non-contradiction, which can be expressed "Being is" or "Whatever is, is".

Comment: Why does it seem to you that it implies that everything is a self-subsisting being? If we have some self-subsisting being, then that being exists by itself and that is different than saying that some being just *de facto* exists (ie. that it exists by no-thing).

Comment: @Thom I don't see the difference. What do you mean by "no-thing", exactly? Also, study the [Thomistic Thesis #1](http://scholastic.us.to/24Thomisticpart2.htm#thesis1): "Potentiality and actuality so divide being that whatsoever exists either is a Pure Actuality [God], or is necessarily composed of potentiality and actuality, as to its primordial and intrinsic principles."

Comment: There are 3 options. First, a thing exists by (in virtue of) itself; second, a thing exists by (in virtue of) something else; third, a thing exists not by itself, not by something else, but just (de facto) exists, ie. that it does not exist "by something" at all, but just, simply, exists. My question is, why the third option is not allowed? You collapse the third option into the first one. Just to be clear, are you saying that when I am saying "something exists by no-thing" that I am trying to interpret something existant by non-existence and that my sentence is therefore without any meaning?

Comment: @Thom A thing that "_just (de facto) exists_" ("_does not exist 'by something' at all, but just, simply, exists_") seems to mean there is no reason for this thing's existence, which is against what the principle of sufficient reason says: "_**Omne** ens_…" or "**Every** thing…".

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for recommendations.

Comment: @Geremia Well, the principle of sufficient reason is exactly what I am bringing into question now (it is quite clear that if I accept the principle of sufficient reason that my question can be answered trivially). I attack it on the ground that there is no reason why to forbid the third option from my earlier comment. You asked me: "What do you mean by "nothing", exactly?", and by no-thing, I mean the absence of every being. My question is: Why collapse the third option to the first and why reject the third option?

Comment: @Thom It seems you're trying to demonstrate/prove the PSR, then. It, like [the principle of non-contradiction, is indemonstrable](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/46668/2014).

Comment: @Geremia Then why think it is true? It seems experiences from this world can just make it more probable but can not give sure knowledge.

Comment: @Thom Read [this quote from _Sententia libri Metaphysicæ_ lib. 4 l. 6 \[607.\]](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/46668/2014). If everything were demonstrable, there would be an infinite regress (cf. [the infinite regress problem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#RegPro)).

Comment: @Thom Also see [Thomistic Thesis](http://scholastic.us.to/24Thomisticpart2.htm) #3: «in the exclusive domain of existence itself God alone subsists, He alone is the most simple. Everything else, which participates in existence, has a nature whereby existence is restricted, and is composed of essence and existence as of two really distinct principles.» and St. Thomas's short work [_On Being & Essence_](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeEnte&Essentia.htm).

Comment: @Geremia I read it. I agree with that regarding the principle of non-contradiction. I know we need to start from some indemonstrable statements. But how to choose these statements in a non-aribtrary way? I agree that I need to accept the principle of non-contradiction without demonstration. But why the principle of sufficient reason?

Comment: With Thomism there is that connection with creator God. This is what makes the universe intelligible. Nothing just hangs loose.

Comment: @Thom PSR can be reduced to PNC via a *reductio ad absurdum* argument. See what I added to my answer.

Comment: @Geremia I concede your point. Reginald Garrigou Lagrange explains it very well. Thank you for great answers as always.

Comment: @Thom Is the statement: "what is neither _positively its own reason_ for existence nor derives this reason _from something else_" (p. 188) your "third option"? He responds that it "is not only unintelligible, but also absurd and impossible, and cannot be distinguished from nothingness. In fact, intelligibility, like possibility, cannot be conceived except in relation to _being_. That is possible which is capable of existing, and that is intelligible which has reference to being, the primary object of the intellect \[cf. [Thomistic Thesis #18](http://scholastic.us.to/24Thomisticpart2.htm)]."

Comment: @Geremia Yes, that is what I called the third option.

Comment: @Thom He attributes it to Hume. I was reminded of Hume when I read your "third option", too.

Comment: @Geremia I read some metaphysics textbook which said that third option was obviously impossible. I wanted to investigate that further and Lagrange explains it very well. What are some metaphysics textbooks that you know of (if you know of any) which are written in a theorem-proof style so that one can clearly perceive what follows from what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94226/discussion-between-geremia-and-thom).

Answer (score 6):

There isn't really a ubiquitous reading of the principle of sufficient reason (PSR), so I think it's worth going over some distinctions and different formulations.

There are at least two major formulations of the PSR, and several sub-formulations of each of the two major formulations (my six below are by no means exhaustive). The first major formulation is in terms of explanation and the second is in terms of causation. Edward Feser, a contemporary Thomist, discusses both in *[Scholastic Metaphysics](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5458)*. In his terminology, he calls the explanatory version the PSR and the causal version the principle of causality (PC). I'll do the same, and I think it may be the PC that Thomists in particular are interested in.

The PSR comes in several sub-formulations, in terms of true propositions, beings, and events (and not everyone who accepts one formulation will accept the others):

1. For any true proposition, p, there is a sufficient explanation for the truth of p
2. For any existing being, b, there is a sufficient explanation for why b exists
3. For any event, e, there is a sufficient explanation for why e occurs

The PC comes in several sub-formulations too:

1. Whatever is a compound of act and potency (i.e. has actual properties, but also has properties that it could potentially have, but does not actually have), has an external, already actual cause for why some properties become actualized, and some merely remain as potential properties. (See Edward Feser's *[Five Proofs for the Existence of God](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6742)*, chapter titled *The Aristotelian Proof*, and his book *[Scholastic Metaphysics](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5458)*, the section titled *2.3 The Principle of Causality* for more on this.)
2. Whatever has its existence distinct from its essence, must have been caused to exist by something external to it. (See Edward Feser's *[Five Proofs for the Existence of God](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6742)*, the chapter titled *The Thomistic Proof*.)
3. Whatever *begins* to exist, must have an external cause of its coming into existence. (This is from William Lane Craig's Kalam cosmological argument.)

There are two noteworthy differences between the two version:

1. In the PC *not* everything has a cause; only things that are compounds of act and potency, essence and existence, or that begin to exist have a cause. In the explanatory PSR, *yes* everything (true propositions, beings, events) does indeed have an *explanation*.
2. In the PC, causes are always external to the thing being caused, since the idea of something being self-causing is absurd. But in the explanatory PSR, things can indeed be self-explaining (such as necessary beings, or beings for which there exists a successful ontological argument).

These two points are important to keep in mind because in your question you phrase the PSR as "Everything that exists must exist by something". If we're talking about the *causal PC*, then as Geremia says, no Thomist would accept this because God is something which is uncaused. If we're talking about the *explanatory PSR*, then "Everything that exists must exist by something" is true, but that is because we're taking about explanation and some things can be self explaining, namely God (but he's certainly not self-causing).

**Getting back to your actual question...**

In *Scholastic Metaphyics*, Feser considers four arguments for the (act-potency version of the) PC: appeals to self-evidence, empirical arguments, arguments from the PNC (principle of non-contradiction), and arguments from the PSR (the explanatory version). The arguments from self-evidence and empirical arguments are basically as you would expect. As for the argument from the PNC, he agrees with you that the PNC does not imply the PC, and writes "Some Thomists explicitly reject attempts to argue from PNC to PC." He notes that there doesn't seem to be an explicit contradiction in negating the PC, and attempts to derive a contradiction can be defended against, by the very act-potency distinction that Thomists want to embrace. Feser writes:

> Now if we think of causation as essentially a matter of there first being a moment when a thing in no way has being, and then a later moment when it has being, then it is indeed hard to see any outright contradiction in the idea that this transition might lack a cause. But for the Scholastic that is the wrong way to characterize the situation. We should think instead of a thing’s potency for existence (which is not nothing even if it is not actual) being actualized at any particular instant it exists (and not merely by a temporally precedent cause).
>
> Now seen in this light it may not seem so clear that denying PC does not involve a contradiction. For if the critic of PC is saying that a thing’s potential for existence can be actualized at a given instant without there being anything that does the actualizing, does that not entail that he is saying that the thing is at that instant both potential and actual with respect to its existence? And is that not a contradiction?
>
> But that inference too would be too quick. For of course, the Scholastic himself says that a thing is at any instant both potential and actual. There is no contradiction here, because a thing is potential and actual in different respects. It is in potency with respect to its essence, but in act with respect to its existence. Now the critic of PC, it seems, can appeal to this very difference in order to defend himself against the charge of contradiction.

Finally, he offers an argument for the PC from the explanatory PSR. (Note, that Feser himself rejects the true-proposition version of the PSR, and where explanation is understood as implication so that the explanans logically imply the explanandum. He understands explanation as "making something intelligible") He writes:

> So the argument from PNC to PC appears to fail. However, a more
> popular approach among Scholastic writers to demonstrating PC is to
> appeal to the principle of sufficient reason. (Cf. Gardeil 1967, pp.
> 22728; Phillips 1950, pp. 235-37; Renard 1946, p. 125-27) PSR states
> that “everything is intelligible” (Garrigou-Lagrange 1939, p. 181),
> and that “there is a sufficient reason or adequate necessary objective
> explanation for the being of whatever is and for all attributes of any
> being” (Wuellner 1956b, p. 15). But if PC were false -- if the
> actualization of a potency, the existence of a contingent thing, or
> something’s changing or coming into being could lack a cause — then
> these phenomena would not be intelligible, would lack a sufficient
> reason or adequate explanation. Hence if PSR is true, PC must be true.
> PC is an application of PSR to things that are mixtures of act and
> potency and essence and existence, and which therefore – unlike God,
> who as pure actuality and subsistent being itself has the sufficient
> reason or adequate explanation for his existence within himself –
> require an explanation by reference to something outside them.

Comment: The first § of ch. 5 of [_Five Proofs_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6742) is a very good overview of PSR.

Comment: Also, Dr. Feser discusses PSR beginning ~19min. into his lecture "[Classical Theism and the Nature of God](https://mediasite.stthom.edu/Mediasite/Play/25a8d43b240642439e6959b07bfaaa291d)" (from the [Aquinas Lecture Series](https://www.stthom.edu/Academics/Centers-of-Excellence/Center-for-Thomistic-Studies/Multimedia/Videos.aqf)).

Answer (score 4):

In mediaeval philosophy, the verb " existing" is sometimes used in its strict sense.

Strictly speaking " existing" means " standing out of its causes".

The verb existing in this sense does not apply to God. For only an (1) actual being ( not a being "in potentia") (2) that is finite, in other words, that has a cause can be said to " exist".

If "existing" is taken in this strict sense, then the proposition " everything that exists has a cause" cannot be proved, since it is a tautology.

References :

Etienne Gilson, Being and some philosophers.

Etienne Gilson, History of Mediaeval philosophy.

Maritain on "existence " : https://books.google.fr/books?id=edXRIxIyc3wC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=maritain,+being+existere,+outside+of+its+causes&source=bl&ots=jgt6xrWKQY&sig=ACfU3U1UFU_xBiAQHTCrN-M1zu6ZQxLCrw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJ-ff40L3iAhXk0eAKHTEHCDYQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=maritain%2C%20being%20existere%2C%20outside%20of%20its%20causes&f=false