# In which part of his treatise on law does Thomas Aquinas provide rules for ranking basic goods?

Tags: philosophy-of-law, aquinas

I know that it provides such rules as I read it in an article but there was no reference to this statement.

Comment: See Question 94 Article 2 of Treatise on Law. Famous natural law theorists have written on this subject (John Finnis, Germain Grisez).

Answer (score 1):

[*Summa Theologica* I-II q. 94 a. 2](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS094.html#FSQ94A2THEP1) co.:

1. Being
   <sup>([principle of non-contradiction](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/46668/2014): "the same thing cannot be affirmed and denied at the same time")</sup>
2. The good
   <sup>(principle of practical reason: "good is that which all things seek after.")</sup>

   1. as "whatever is a means of preserving human life, and of warding off its obstacles"
   2. "according to that nature which he has in common with other animals", "such as sexual intercourse, education of offspring and so forth."
   3. "according to the nature of his reason", "to know the truth about God, and to live in society"; "for instance, to shun ignorance, to avoid offending those among whom one has to live, and other such things"

On Friss-Grisez's "conventional natural law theory" view, see:

- Hittinger, [*A Critique of the New Natural Law Theory*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9049), ch. 2 "Natural Law, Moral Principles, and Ends", pp. 49-92

<sup>tip [Prof Leon's comment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91277/in-which-part-of-his-treatise-on-law-does-thomas-aquinas-provide-rules-for-ranki#comment256649_91277)</sup>

Comment: A PDF of the Summa Theologica may be found here: http://www.sophia-project.org/uploads/1/3/9/5/13955288/aquinas_law.pdf

Comment: @MarkAndrews cf. also [Freddoso's transl.](https://www3.nd.edu/~afreddos/summa-translation/TOC-part1-2.htm): [Q. 94:  The Natural Law](http://www.nd.edu/%7Eafreddos/summa-translation/Part%201-2/st1-2-ques94.pdf).